# Try catch block catches error but React Native still throws an exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented error handling in my React Native app but an Error that is being caught still throws an exception.

Here I am authorizing a phone number for phone number auth using Firebase:

```js
export const authorizeFirebase = (phoneNumber) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  firebase.auth()
    .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    .on('state_changed', async (phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
      switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
        case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFIED: // or 'verified'

          resolve(phoneAuthSnapshot);
          break;

        case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.CODE_SENT: // or 'sent'
          resolve(phoneAuthSnapshot);
          break;

        case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT: // or 'timeout'
          resolve(phoneAuthSnapshot);
          break;

        case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.ERROR: // or 'error'
          reject(phoneAuthSnapshot.error);
          break;

        default:
          reject(phoneAuthSnapshot.error);
          break;
      }
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
});
```

If I force an error and the promise above enters rejected state, the try catch block the `authorizeFirebase`catches the error:

```js
export const verifyPhoneNumber = (
  phoneNumber,
  setSubmittedPhoneNumber,
    setShowError,
    navigate,
) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { state, verificationId } = await authorizeFirebase(phoneNumber);

        if (state === 'verified') {
      await authenticateFirebaseUser({ providerId: 'phone' });
      dispatch(attemptAuth());
    }

        if (state === 'sent') {
      navigate('EnterNameAndSmsCode', { verificationId });
        }

        setSubmittedPhoneNumber(false);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error message', error.message); // try catch block catches the error here
        console.log('error code', error.code);

        let errorMessage;
        if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-phone-number') errorMessage = invalidPhoneNumberErrorMsg;
        if (error.code === 'auth/unknown') errorMessage = error.message.slice(15);

        setSubmittedPhoneNumber(false);

    setShowError({
            error: true,
            errorMessage,
        });
    logger.error(error, 'phone number verifcation'); // custom error logger
  }
};
```

If I am handling the error, shouldn't I expect the exception not to be thrown, crashing the app? How do I stop the 'Red Box' showing up if I am handling the error in my try catch block? I am also wrapping the app in an ErrorBoundary.

Comment: Maybe you're catching the error but there's something else which must be outputting another error?

Comment: Do you found any solution. I am also facing this

Comment: Any update at all? Am also experiencing this one and its driving me crazy. Seems to be async/await related.

Comment: Ok so as far as I can remember, I wasn't catching the error in the right place. Remember that a try catch block only catches the error for the method that you call inside it, so the error may be being thrown not where you think it is..